# Ethernet connection to FLIR ADK

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ethernet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I have a FLIR ADK camera with GMSL/Ethernet connection and NOT USB. The vendor said it works better without the usb connection. However, I am having issues finding drivers or getting it run on Autoware. What is the procedure of getting the video feed from that camera and displaying and eventually using it on Autoware and RIVZ? (A USB camera would be listed in
v4l2-ctl  , however since this is connected via Ethernet it doesn't show there)

Currently I have the spinnaker sdk installed that allows me to connect to the camera and see the video feed. But, I would like to direct that to autoware so that I can calibrate it with the LiDAR. Is there a generic way of connecting Ethernet cameras to autoware or ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342538/ethernet-connection-to-flir-adk/) by [msaeUF](https://answers.ros.org/users/51019/msaeuf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2020-01-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2020-01-26**:
When you say "FLIR ADK" camera, which exact model do you mean?

**Comment by [msaeUF](https://answers.ros.org/users/51019/msaeuf/) on 2020-01-29**:
It doesn't say.
https://www.flir.com/globalassets/imported-assets/document/flir-adk-datasheet-en.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved it.
The driver is available at:
https://github.com/FLIR/flir_adk_ethernet

Initially when i tried there were xml issues but the gentleman who made it fixed it. It should be working now.

---

Originally posted by [msaeUF](https://answers.ros.org/users/51019/msaeuf/) with karma: 53 on 2020-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0